# Cannot add dznsegmentedcontrol to UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uisegmentedcontrol

I am trying to add the following control to a UIView that is inside a viewcontroller. The control does not seem to appear inside the view.

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/dznsegmentedcontrol

```
NSArray *items = @[@"Kicks", @"Re-kicks", @"Interested"];

DZNSegmentedControl *control = [[DZNSegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:items];
control.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
control.delegate = self;
control.selectedSegmentIndex = 2;
[control addTarget:self action:@selector(selectedSegment:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

[cell.segmentView addSubview:control];
```

Comment: "It does not seem to be working" is not a question. Say what you expect and what actually happens, please.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is to add the controller somehow.

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:self.control];
```

or as in the example code givin by dzenbot:

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.control;
```